# C# Date Time Picket checked value

Tags: datetimepicker

How to get the state of the dateTimePicker when checked is true and when checked is false , from this code. I set its ShowCheckBox = true

```
foreach (Control formCtrl in form.Controls)
{
    if (formCtrl  is DateTimePicker)
        { 
            if (formCtrl.Checked == true) // Here it gets error
              { 
                MessageBox.Show("Checked");
              }
               else { 
                       MessageBox.Show("UnChecked");
                    }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I declared a new control as a DateTimePicker but equal to the existing variable formCtrl

```
foreach (Control formCtrl in form.Controls)
{
if (formCtrl  is DateTimePicker)
    { 
    DateTimePicker dtpNew = formCtrl as DateTimePicker;//Solution
        if (dtpNew.Checked == true)
          { 
            MessageBox.Show("Checked");
          }
           else { 
                   MessageBox.Show("UnChecked");
                }
     }
}
```